# Using Jquery AJAX POST for form authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have the following form:

```
<form name="myForm" action="welcome.java" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="ticketnummer">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And the following AJAX POST:

```
var data = {"function": "List", "teamId": "****", "teamKey":"****"}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    url: 'http://fys.securidoc.nl/Ticket',
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        alert('success!');
    }
});
```

I want my users to log in through their "ticketnumber". A list of all ticketNumbers is located at "http://fys.securidoc.nl/Ticket" as you can see. If the user enters one of those ticketNumbers in the list he/she gets access to the welcome page. Now my question is how can i make this happen? I have tried alot but i can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: Could you maybe post what you've tried?

Comment: Well i think the main problem is, is  that i don't now how to compare the user input with the data response.

Comment: that link is currently throwing a 504 error. Can you edit the question with a sample of what the response data looks like? Really you shouldn't expose all the ticket numbers in a list (which is how you've described it) - just allow the user to submit their number, then on the server-side check it's valid, and if so then return an authentication token of some sort which the user can use to verify themselves on the other pages. Or store their login status in the server-side session or something.

Comment: On a more general point though, I'm pretty sure there will be frameworks for this sort of situation - generally rolling your own security is a bad idea, it's complicated and you're likely to make some sort of subtle mistake which will allow the security to be compromised.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what i want to do! The user has to submit a number and on the server side it has to check if its valid. however i don't know how to accomplish that.

Comment: which part are you struggling with? currently you're submitting everything except the ticket number itself, is it that which is the problem? Or is it the server-side code that's the problem?